# MySQL / delete from / Why is it so slow?

Tags: mysql

could you kindly help me in the following?

The MySQL command below runs over 4 seconds on a modern PC where nothing else is run, even when run multiple times:

```
DELETE FROM table1
WHERE column1 LIKE 'pattern1%' AND
      column2 IN (SELECT column3 FROM table2 WHERE column4 = 'pattern2')
```

table1 contains approx. 1100 record of which 95% matches column1 / pattern1%.

table2 contains approx. 5000 of which close to zero ones match column4 / pattern2.

Host: MySQL v5.7, Ubuntu 16 64 bit, fast SSD, InnoDB pool mem is 1 GB

Could it done in a more simple or faster way? Thanks.

Query plan:

```
+----+--------------------+--------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type        | table  | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+--------------------+--------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | DELETE             | table1 | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1179 |   100.00 | Using where |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | table2 | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 4601 |     1.00 | Using where |
+----+--------------------+--------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: Please show the query plan

Comment: are column1 and column2 indexed? can you show us the create table code for table1?

Comment: Other than indices this query looks fairly optimal to me.  Please try running `EXPLAIN` on it.

Comment: What are your computer's specifications? 'Modern computer' isn't helpful here as 'modern computer' could easily be a Celeron with 2GB of RAM.

Comment: BTW, select count(*) from runs close to zero sec. / explain delete is here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23505237/

Comment: No indexes used because the tables change constantly. The HW is: 2 CPUs @ 2.4 Ghz w/ 4 MB L2 cache + 2 GB of RAM.

Comment: If you try using the SELECT operator with the same WHERE is it slow?

Comment: Yeah.. that's very weak for running a DBMS + normal applications like a browser. No doubt that contributes to the slowness that you're experiencing, combined with table index issues.

Comment: what happen if you replace `delete` with `select *`? is it still over 4 second run?

Comment: Need clarification, are
`SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1 LIKE 'pattern1%'` and 
`SELECT column3 FROM table2 WHERE column4 = 'pattern2'` both fast...?
then please check is `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1 LIKE 'pattern1%' AND column2 IN ('value1', 'value2', 'value3' )` also fast?
if yes then i think i know the solution

Comment: Replacing delete with select * is very fast and runs close to zero sec. And all the 3 select queries you provided runs in zero sec too. So select is fast in all cases. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the size of your tables and your indexes configuration.

For example, if table2 is not too big, properly indexed by column4, and the result of the subselect is not big either, you could reverse the order of the conditions so that the column2 condition executes first, and if it doesn't match, it won't bother executing the potentially slower column1 like query.

```
DELETE FROM table1
WHERE column2 IN (SELECT column3 FROM table2 WHERE column4 = 'pattern2') AND
      column1 LIKE 'pattern1%'
```

Comment: Thanks, I will test it in a day and write the result.

Comment: As is shown in the query plan, there is no index on column 4. That really needs to be there to get good performance.

Comment: @Arjan: I will check it with an index, though the EXPLAIN does not show a speedup with an index as I see.

Answer (score 1):

It appears from the `EXPLAIN` query that your table(s) does not have properly set indexes. Indexes are used to find rows with specific column values quickly.

One of the most important use from performance perspective of indexes is to  find the **rows matching** a `WHERE` clause **quickly**. Without an index, MySQL **must** begin with the first row and then read through the **entire table** to find the relevant rows. The larger the table, the more this costs. If the table has an index for the columns in question, MySQL can quickly determine the position to seek to in the middle of the data file without having to look at all the data. This is much faster than reading every row sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add indexes to speed up your query. At the very least there should be an index on `column 4` in `table 2`. You probably want to create a combined index on `(column 4, column3)`.

Since you indicate that about 95% of all rows in `table 1` match on `column 1`, there's really no point in adding an index for `column 1`. If the number of matches for `column 2` is relatively small, you could add an index for that column.

Comment: I did not want to use indexes because these tables change constantly and fast (every minute).

Comment: If you do a lot of insert queries, you'll want to keep the number of indexes low. But for other queries you'll needs some indexes, and in this case you can't do without.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally solved it by adding an index to table2 / column3. Thanks Everyone for your helps.